# Bad Request error when posting data using jQuery in IE only

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, knockout.js, sammy.js

I've written a small single-page application using Knockout.js and Sammy.js, plus jQuery for posting data back to the server.

This works fine in Firefox, but all my POSTs are getting a "400 Bad Request" response in IE.

I've used Fiddler to see what's going on, and the only difference I can see is that IE includes the hash in the Referer header, but I don't think that should cause a problem.

Here's my jQuery post:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/App_Presentation/BDM/RdmUserCategoryService.svc/GetUserCategoryUsersByCategory',
data: '{ "categoryId" : "' + this.params.catId + '" }',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf=8',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
    self.editCategoryData({
        CategoryID: ko.observable(categoryId),
        CategoryName: ko.observable(categoryName),
        UserList: ko.observableArray([])
    });

    self.editCategoryData().UserList(data.d);
}});
```

The method on the server doesn't get hit, and the success callback doesn't get hit either. When I add an error callback, the only information I get is the "Bad Request" error message.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What server technology are you hitting with this? ASP? PHP? Excuse me I jumped the gun. I see your URL is pointing to SVC file. So WCF?

Comment: Can you confirm that Sammy is properly setting `params.catId`? Just trying to rule anything out here. Also can you post some sort of screenshot of the network traffic in IE and Fiddler?

Comment: I've stepped through the JavaScript and the params.catId value is getting set correctly. And yes, the server is a WCF service.

I've run a trace on the WCF service and it's getting an exception trying to process the request of "Cannot process contentType". However, there's pretty much nothing on Google about this, and I don't know why it would work in FF but not IE?!

Comment: What does the `contenttype` look like in both browsers. Anything different?

Comment: Unfortunately not. In requests from both browsers, Fiddler shows it as: application/json; charset=utf=8

Comment: Maybe try removing the `charset` from the `contentType`? I know this is a witchhunt but I'm wondering if it is necessary in this case.

Comment: You've nailed it - thanks very much.

Comment: Awesome. I imagine it is the way that each browser was handling the encoding. Your WCF might've found it to not agree with what was stated in the `contentType`.

Comment: I guess so. I'm not even sure why I included the encoding type, I don't think I'd do that normally. Not to worry. If you write that up as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Oops. I was just doing that. Ha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So anyone else viewing this may try a solution to this problem. Try removing `charset` from your `contentType`. It worked for the problem above.

It could have to do with slight encoding differences between the two browsers, WCF may reject the incoming request given the encoding of the request doesn't actually match the encoding specified in the `contentType`. While this isn't a sure fire solid answer. It's the best I have.

Final Code:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/App_Presentation/BDM/RdmUserCategoryService.svc/GetUserCategoryUsersByCategory',
data: '{ "categoryId" : "' + this.params.catId + '" }',
contentType: 'application/json'
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
    self.editCategoryData({
        CategoryID: ko.observable(categoryId),
        CategoryName: ko.observable(categoryName),
        UserList: ko.observableArray([])
    });

    self.editCategoryData().UserList(data.d);
}});
```